# check if a period is included between two dates

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

i've a mysql table like this:

```
   | ID | ID_period | date_start |  date_end  |
   | 1  |   1       | 0000-07-01 | 0000-08-31 |
   | 2  |   2       | 0000-09-01 | 0000-10-30 |
   | 3  |   3       | 0000-11-01 | 0000-12-28 |
   | 4  |   4       | 0000-11-01 | 0000-03-31 |
```

how can i select IDs that are included between this period 0000/07/14 - 0000/08/25 ?

date_start and date_end columns are DATE format.

THE PROBLEM is that if i search for a period (included and intersect) that is ie: from 0000-12-12 to 0000-01-25 i get 0 records from the select, i guess for the year that is '0000'.. how can i fix it ?

another problem is that if i search a period like 11-01 to 12-31 i got 0 results.. because last day od december in date_end is 28.. but if i search for a period 11-01 to 12-31 is because i want all the records included.. so i'd like to get the record having id=3 and id=4

at the moment im using the following query:

```
SELECT ... WHERE '12' BETWEEN MONTH(date_start) and MONTH(date_end)
AND '15' BETWEEN DAY(date_start) and DAY(date_end)
AND '03' BETWEEN MONTH(date_start) and MONTH(date_end)
AND '28' BETWEEN DAY(date_start) and DAY(date_end)
```

Comment: You mean all the IDS that overlap with that period or fully included in that period? In your example this doesn't seem to matter but probably in your real data it might.

Comment: What do you mean by "included"? Completely within or intersect?

Comment: THE PROBLEM is that if i search for a period (included and intersect) that is ie: from 0000-12-12 to 0000-01-25 i get 0 records from the select, i guess for the year that is '0000'.. how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   date_start BETWEEN '0000-07-14' AND '0000-08-25'
        OR date_end BETWEEN '0000-07-14' AND '0000-08-25'
        OR (date_start<'0000-07-14' AND date_end>'0000-08-25')
```

Comment: THE PROBLEM is that if i search for a period (included and intersect) that is ie: from 0000-12-12 to 0000-01-25 i get 0 records from the select, i guess for the year that is '0000'.. how can i fix it ?

Comment: 12-12 to 01-25? Can end date be smaller than start date?

Comment: crap.. so how to find the record that has a period like 12-12 to 01-15 so?

Comment: I ALWAYS did `date_start < oth_date_end and date_end > oth_date_start` in MSSQL. But, MySQL seems to prefer this solution. Strange... I'll investigate the plan some other time. Thanks! P.S.: it was so slow in MySQL that I look for another aproaches and found this answer.